# what happened to my intellitrace option in VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio

On a fresh install of VS? intellitrace is enabled but I cant turn it off.

[image]

Comment: What [edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx) do you use? What edition did you use before?

Comment: VS 2015 PRO - clean install on new machine

Comment: And for second question?

Comment: I've used many editions of VS on other machines. Lets say VS 2015 Enterprise